# What type of Cron Schedule is this?

Tags: cron

```
0 48 16 ? * MON-FRI
```

What is this? All the cron examples I see on the internet is minutes at the start. But this cron job runs Mon-Fri, every week at 16:48 hrs.

The 0 at the start and the ? throws me off here. This code is written in Java using quartz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost answered your own question.  This is not an actual `cron` schedule.  This is a Quartz schedule.

Quartz is guilty of using confusing terminology by referring to this as a "Cron Expression" (see http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html).  I suppose calling it a `CronLikeExpression` or an `InspiredByCronExpression` would have been too wordy.

You'll see from that JavaDoc page that the `0` at the beginning is the value of a **seconds** field and the `?` in the **day-of-month** field means "any day of the month".